# load_java_part error while using activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter with Jruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am stuck with a problem for a very long time and i have hit a dead end with desperate need of a solution.
I have a web application which has to to be ported to WAR on Windows 7.The database I am using is Sqlit3.
**Ruby Version** :- ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32] 
**JRuby Version** :- jruby 9.0.5.0 (2.2.3) 2016-01-26 7bee00d Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.45
-b08 on 1.7.0_45-b18 +jit [Windows 7-amd64] 
**Rails Version** :- Rails 4.2.6

Before porting it to WAR ,these are the steps i do.These steps has worked in many Systems,But for few systems I am not able to get through,
1)I installed JRuby.
2)I installed rails on Jruby by running **gem install rails -N**
3)I removed the **gem sqlite3** and add  **gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'** (to make it java compatible)

After bundle install,

When I run **rails c** command ,

I get the below Exception,

*activerecord-jdbc-adapter is for use with JRuby only
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1
.3.20/lib/arjdbc/sqlite3/adapter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`l
oad_java_part' for ArJdbc:Module (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-j
dbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/sqlite3.rb:2:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-j
dbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/sqlite3.rb:2:in`'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-j
dbcsqlite3-adapter-1.3.20/lib/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-j
dbcsqlite3-adapter-1.3.20/lib/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter.rb:3:in`'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in`require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
        from D:/srikanth-work/simple/config/application.rb:7:in`

> '
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6
>   /lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6
>   /lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in`block in server'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6
>   /lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6
>   /lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`server'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6
>   /lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6
>   /lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
>           from bin/rails:4:in `require'
>           from bin/rails:4:in`'*

Any suggestion would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

**activerecord-jdbc-adapter is for use with JRuby** means you're loading it under non-JRuby (MRI)

Bundler has platform specifiers if you need to run under JRuby and MRI using a single *Gemfile* :

`gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapte', platform: :jruby`

Comment: I build the deployed on tomcat..
When opened the application on browser I got the below error, 
exit from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:852:in exit' from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:815

Answer (score -2):

I build the deployed on tomcat..
When opened the application on browser I got the below error, 
exit from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:852:in exit' from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:815:inexit' from D:/sotwares/Tomcats/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/webapps/helloworld/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb:14:in (root)' from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040:inrequire' from /D:/sotwares/Tomcats/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/webapps/helloworld/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.24.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1:in (root)' from /D:/sotwares/Tomcats/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/webapps/helloworld/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.24.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:inrequire' from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040:in require' from D:/sotwares/Tomcats/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/webapps/helloworld/WEB-INF/config/boot.rb:3:in(root)' from /D:/sotwares/Tomcats/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/webapps/helloworld/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.24.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1:in (root)' from /D:/sotwares/Tomcats/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/webapps/helloworld/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.24.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:inrequire' from file:/D:/sotwares/Tomcats/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/webapps/helloworld/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.20.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment3.rb:23:in `load_environment' You're seeing this error because you use JRuby::Rack::ErrorApp::ShowStatus

Comment: the reason i was gettin errors was because i was trying to install rails on jruby.... and run it directly as rails commands. I was successfuly able to by using only jruby -S commands instead of installing rails on jruby